# Error select based on selection from 1st select in React Hooks and dinamically inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two selects and I want to populate the second select base in the selection of the first one in react.  When I select a countrie I want a select2 be displayed with its states and the value on the second select be updated with the value chose.

I have the following code,

```
const MyForm = (props) => {    
    const COUNTRIES = [
        {
            displayValue: "Country1",
            value: "C1"
        },
        {
            displayValue: "Country2",
            value: "C2"
        }
    ]        
    const STATES = {
        "": [ {
            displayValue: "",
            value: ""
        }],
        "C1": [{
            displayValue: "State 1",
            value: "S11"
        },
        {
            displayValue: "State 2",
            value: "S12"
        }],
        "C2": [{
            displayValue: "State n1",
            value: "C21"
        },
        {
            displayValue: "STate n2",
            value: "C22"
        }]
    }    
    let inputsForms = {
      country: {
          elementType: 'select',
          elementConfig: {
              type: 'select',
              placeholder: '',
              options: COUNTRIES,
              firstOption: "-- Choose Country"
          },
          value: ''
      },
      states: {
        elementType: 'select',
        elementConfig: {
            type: 'select',
            placeholder: '',
            options: [], // I need these options depend on the countrie selected  STATES["C1"]
            firstOption: "-- Choose States"
        },
        value: ''
    }      
  }
        
  const [myForm, setmyForm] = useState(inputsForms);

  const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
        return {
            ...oldObject,
            ...updatedProperties
        };
    };  
  
  const inputChangedHandler = (e, controlName) => {
    const countrieValue = controlName ==="country"?e.target.value:"";
    const stateOptions = myForm["states"].elementConfig;
    stateOptions["options"] = STATES[countrieValue];

      const updatedControls = updateObject(myForm, {
          [controlName]: updateObject(myForm[controlName], {
            value: e.target.value
          })
        });

        setmyForm(updatedControls);

  }


  const ElementsArray = [];
  for (let key in myForm) {
      ElementsArray.push({
          id: key,
          config: myForm[key]
      });
  }

  let form = (
      <form>
          {ElementsArray.map(el => (
              <Input 
              key={el.id}
              elementType={el.config.elementType}
              elementConfig={el.config.elementConfig}
              value={el.config.value}              
              changed={e => inputChangedHandler(e, el.id)}
              firstOption={el.config.firstOption}
          />
              ))}
          
      </form>
      
          );

  return(
        <div>
            {form}
        </div>
  );
}

export default MyForm;
```

The options charge on the select2, however when I select an option on the second select, the options dissappear and the value of the select2 is not updated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As inputChangeHandler is getting called every input change, the data is resetting even there is change in the state. You could check for the contrieValue and set the state data so the data is not reset.

```js
const inputChangedHandler = (e, controlName) => {
  const countrieValue = controlName === "country" ? e.target.value : "";
  if (countrieValue) {
    const stateOptions = myForm["states"].elementConfig;
    stateOptions["options"] = STATES[countrieValue];

    const updatedControls = updateObject(myForm, {
      [controlName]: updateObject(myForm[controlName], {
        value: e.target.value
      })
    });

    setmyForm(updatedControls);

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right about the reason for the error, what do you suggest to correct it? I tried with if (countrieValue) and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a kind of conditional to update the state whenever *the state* is selected so that it does not affect the original country object.

```
const inputChangedHandler = (e, controlName) => {
  if (countrolName === 'states') {
    // your logic here
    return;
  }

  const countrieValue = controlName === 'country' ? e.target.value : '';
  const stateOptions = myForm['states'].elementConfig;
  stateOptions['options'] = STATES[countrieValue];

  const updatedControls = updateObject(myForm, {
    [controlName]: updateObject(myForm[controlName], {
      value: e.target.value,
    }),
  });

  setmyForm(updatedControls);
};
```

Comment: yes, you're right, but I still don't know what the logic would be like.

Comment: You need the states value right?  So, you need to store it on react state as setState(e.target.value).

Comment: You are right, the solution was to store the values in the state, thaaaaaaanks.